# Asking about how to say to a possible supervisor to give me some time as I look for funding opportunities

Tags: graduate-admissions, advisor, funding, communication

I am a masters student in mathematics at an Asian University and I mailed my CV to some professors in France for phd position in analytic number theory.

> One of the professors said that his university currently doesn't have doctoral scholarship grant and said that he would be happy to supervise my thesis if I get funding from other organizations.
>
> My question is how should I reply him to tell him to give me some time as I look for funding opportunities and ask my parents if they can fund me if I don't get any funding.
>
> What should be my language so as to clearly tell him that I am really serious about this opportunity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just say it like you have here. Thanks, I'm seeking funding, I'll need some time.

The professor understands that time is needed. It would be good, however, that you say you will let him know as soon as you have more information, but in, say, three months in any case.

If you want to do more, ask him to point you to any papers that you might study during this period.